# Can Color and MarkerFaceColor be automated while using the gscatter command?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm searching for a way to automatically include marker `Color` and `MarkerFaceColor` while plotting with the `gscatter` function. For example, I can plot the weight versus MPG using the command below:

```
load carsmall;
gscatter(Weight,MPG,Model_Year,'','xos');
h = gscatter(Weight, MPG, Model_Year,'','o');
set(h(1), 'Color', 'b', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');
set(h(2), 'Color', 'g', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g');
set(h(3), 'Color', 'r', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');
```

But since `gscatter` doesn't contain the functionality to set the `Color` or `MarkerFaceColor`, I have to do this manually.

Does anyone know of a technique that will allow for this to be done automatically?

Comment: what do you mean with "automatically"? what is wrong with your code? Everything seems alright.´(except, that you have two identical scatter plots)

Answer (score 1):

`gscatter` does contain the ability to add colors (it's in the part you have as `''` before the marker type).  'MarkerFaceColor' has to be adjusted separately; you can define a list of colors initially and loop over them.  Note that the color and marker lists don't have to be the same size as the number of groups, so this will work for anywhere between one and eight groups:

```
colors = 'rgbcmykw'
h = gscatter(Weight, MPG, Model_Year,colors,'o');
for n = 1:length(h)
  set(h(n), 'MarkerFaceColor', colors(n));
end
```